# JPA persist entities with one to many relation

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, persistence

Config

- EcliplseLink 2.3.2
- JPA 2.0
- The entities are auto created from the db schema from netbeans with *Entity Classes from Database...* wizard.
- The controller classes are auto created from netbeans with *JPA Controller Classes from Entity Classes...* wizard

**Short version of question**

In a classic scenario, two tables with one to many relation. I create the parent entity, then the child entity and I attach the child to the parent's collection. When I *create* (controller method) the parent entity, I expect the child entity to be created to and associated with parent. Why doesn't it happen?

**Long version**

Parent class

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class Device implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updated;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "deviceId")
    private Collection<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaceCollection;

    public Device() {
    }

    public Device(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        updated = new Date();
    }

    // setters and getters...

    @XmlTransient
    public Collection<NetworkInterface> getNetworkInterfaceCollection() {
        return networkInterfaceCollection;
    }

    public void setNetworkInterfaceCollection(Collection<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaceCollection) {
        this.networkInterfaceCollection = networkInterfaceCollection;
    }

    public void addNetworkInterface(NetworkInterface net) {
        this.networkInterfaceCollection.add(net);
    }

    public void removeNetworkInterface(NetworkInterface net) {
        this.networkInterfaceCollection.remove(net);
    }
    // other methods
}
```

Child class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NETWORK_INTERFACE")
@XmlRootElement
public class NetworkInterface implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updated;
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEVICE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Device deviceId;

    public NetworkInterface() {
    }

    public NetworkInterface(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.updated = new Date();
    }

    // setter and getter methods...

    public Device getDeviceId() {
        return deviceId;
    }

    public void setDeviceId(Device deviceId) {
        this.deviceId = deviceId;
    }
}
```

Main class

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("wifi-dbPU");
        DeviceJpaController deviceController = new DeviceJpaController(emf);
        NetworkInterfaceJpaController netController = new NetworkInterfaceJpaController(emf);

        Device device = new Device("laptop");
        NetworkInterface net = new NetworkInterface("eth0");

        device.getNetworkInterfaceCollection().add(net);
        deviceController.create(device);
    }
}
```

This class throws a NullPointerException in line: `device.getNetworkInterfaceCollection().add(net);`

The system knows that there is a new entity `device` and it has an element `net` in it's collection. I expected it to write `device` in db, get device's id, attach it to `net` and write it in db.

Instead of this, I found that these are the steps I have to do:

```
deviceController.create(device);
net.setDeviceId(device);
device.getNetworkInterfaceCollection().add(net);
netController.create(net);
```

**Why do I have to create the child when the parent class knows it's child and it should create it for me?**

The create method from DeviceJpaController (sorry for the long names in fields, they are auto generated).

```
public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return emf.createEntityManager();
}

public void create(Device device) {
    if (device.getNetworkInterfaceCollection() == null) {
        device.setNetworkInterfaceCollection(new ArrayList<NetworkInterface>());
    }
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Collection<NetworkInterface> attachedNetworkInterfaceCollection = new ArrayList<NetworkInterface>();
        for (NetworkInterface networkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterfaceToAttach : device.getNetworkInterfaceCollection()) {
            networkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterfaceToAttach = em.getReference(networkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterfaceToAttach.getClass(), networkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterfaceToAttach.getId());
            attachedNetworkInterfaceCollection.add(networkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterfaceToAttach);
        }
        device.setNetworkInterfaceCollection(attachedNetworkInterfaceCollection);
        em.persist(device);
        for (NetworkInterface networkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterface : device.getNetworkInterfaceCollection()) {
            Device oldDeviceIdOfNetworkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterface = networkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterface.getDeviceId();
            networkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterface.setDeviceId(device);
            networkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterface = em.merge(networkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterface);
            if (oldDeviceIdOfNetworkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterface != null) {
                oldDeviceIdOfNetworkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaceCollection().remove(networkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterface);
                oldDeviceIdOfNetworkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterface = em.merge(oldDeviceIdOfNetworkInterfaceCollectionNetworkInterface);
            }
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I finally understood the logic behind persisting one to many entities. The process is:

1. Create parent class
2. Persist it
3. Create child class
4. Associate child with parent
5. Persist child (the parent collection is updated)

With code:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("wifi-dbPU");
        DeviceJpaController deviceController = new DeviceJpaController(emf);
        NetworkInterfaceJpaController netController = new NetworkInterfaceJpaController(emf);

        Device device = new Device("laptop");                 // 1
        deviceController.create(device);                      // 2

        NetworkInterface net = new NetworkInterface("eth0");  // 3
        net.setDeviceId(device.getId());                      // 4
        netController.create(net);                            // 5 
        // The parent collection is updated by the above create     
    }
}
```

Now, I can find a device (with id for example) and I can get all its children using

```
Collection<NetworkInterface> netCollection = device.getNetworkInterfaceCollection()
```

In the device entity class, which I posted in the question, there is no need for the methods `addNetworkInterface` and `removeNetwokrInterface`.

Comment: According to what I read from book. `cascade=CascadeType.Persist` should persist all the relations and you only need to update one entity, JPA will navigate thru the relations and update the associated entities. But... I couldn't make it work...

Answer (score 5):

@Dima K is correct in what they say. When you do this:

```
    Device device = new Device("laptop");
    NetworkInterface net = new NetworkInterface("eth0");

    device.getNetworkInterfaceCollection().add(net);
    deviceController.create(device);
```

The collection in device hasn't been initialized and so you get a NPE when trying to add to it. In your `Device` class, when declaring your `Collection`, you can also initialize it:

```
private Collection<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaceCollection = new CollectionType<>();
```

As for persisting, your assumptions are correct but I think the execution is wrong. When you create your device, make it persistent with JPA right away (doing transaction management wherever needed).

```
Device device = new Device("laptop");
getEntityManager().persist(device);
```

Do the same for the NetworkInterface:

```
NetworkInterface net = new NetworkInterface("eth0");
getEntityManager().persist(net);
```

Now since both your entities are persisted, you can add one to the other.

`device.getNetworkInterfaceCollection().add(net);`

JPA should take care of the rest without you having to call any other persists.

Comment: You are both right about the Collection initialization. But this is my question. Why do I have to persist two entities when all I need is to create the collection. Shouldn't the JPA persist all the entities in the collection and associate them with the parent class?

Comment: JPA knows about entities and what state they are in. So creating a device entity and a networkinterface entity does just that. JPA will know about two entities. It is your responsibility to tell it the relationship between the two. I understand what you mean that if you persist the device and add elements to its collection after, that JPA should persist those too. If the collection is populated when you `persist` the device (or vice-versa) then the device and its collections elements will be persisted.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known behavior of collection data members.
The easiest solution is to modify your collection getter to lazily create the collection.

```
@XmlTransient
public Collection<NetworkInterface> getNetworkInterfaceCollection() {
    if (networkInterfaceCollection == null) {
        networkInterfaceCollection = new Some_Collection_Type<NetworkInterface>();
    }
    return networkInterfaceCollection;
}
```

Also, remember to refer to this data member only through the getter method.

Comment: This is done in the `DeviceJpaController` create. See the if in the beginning. If the collection is null, then it creates a new and sets it with the `device.setNetworkInterfaceCollection` method. I tried your's suggest and I get: `IllegalArgumentException: An instance of a null PK has been incorrectly provided for this find operation.`

Answer (score 0):

This exception means you're trying to locate an entity (probably by em.getReference()) that hasn't been persisted yet.
You cannot you em.getReference() or em.find() on entities which still don't have a PK.

Comment: You are right. It tries to locate the net's Id in a em.getReference() call. The id is null because the entity hasn't been persisted yet. Please see the comment at @Sotirios Delimanolis post.

Answer (score -1):

In order to enable save ability on a @OneToMany relation e.g.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="myTable", cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
private List<item> items;
```

Then you have to tell to your @ManyToOne relation that it is allowed to update myTable like this updatable = true

```
@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name="fk_myTable", nullable = false, updatable = true, insertable = true)
```

Comment: `updatable = true, insertable = true` are defaults anyway, so this doesn't fix the issue.